# Маленький дом — это домишко или (допускается) домишка?

Tags: морфология

1) Как правильно: **домишко, домишка,  домишку, домишко,  домишком, домишке**. Это верная парадигма, так она представлена у Зализняка (настоящего)?

А **домишка (И.п.)**? Нельзя сказать: принадлежит домишке, от домишки к домишке?

2) Орфографический словарь (на сайте Грамота.ру) **дает поправку на вариативность окончаний**: домишко, -а и -и, дат. -у и -е, тв. -ом и -ой.

3) Так что же правильно?  И если устарело начальная  форма слова (домишка), то когда она устарела?

4) И как-то странно звучит: *подошли к старому домишку*. Может быть, эти окончания вообще не стоит употреблять? Может быть, **вариативной должна быть только начальная форма: домишко/домишка?**

**Примеры:**

Ему ясно представились утонувшие в воде огороды, осенний вечер, дождь, городовые, шашки, **маленький домишка**... остающийся позади. [К. К. Вагинов.  (1934)]

Но Михайла ...палочкой показывает в ту сторону, где у него раньше стоял, какой ни на есть, **свой домишка**,[С. А. Клычков (1927)]

...ничего не осталось **от домишки,** а у Ивана Сергеича все стекла из окон вылетели  [Б. К. Зайцев. О Шмелеве (1968)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я как раз только что "проходила" это слово...

И в орфографическом словаре там же была; да, он разрешает то и сё.

Но есть словарь поглавнее - Русское словесное ударение,

который не терпит двоякости, а именно указует окончания в Р. п., Д. п., Т. п., предложном:

[**домишко**, -а, -у, -ом, -е; р. *мн.* -шек](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А.
Словарь трудностей русского языка](http://slovana.ru/slovari/trudnostei/slovar-trudnostei-russkogo-yazyka_0173.htm)

---

[Слова мужского рода типа *домишко*](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/sklonenie-imen-suschestvitelnyih-70780.html)

> образуют формы косвенных падежей и по второму, и по первому склонению:
>   р. п.: домишка, домишки; д. п. — домишку, домишке;  в. п. — домишко,
>   домишку; тв. п. — домишком, домишкой; п. п. — о домишке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

РОЗЕНТАЛЬ!

[§ 148. Особенности склонения некоторых слов и словосочетаний](http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xxxvi.html)

> Слово *домишко, заборишко* и т. п. (мужского рода) склоняются по типу
>   имен существительных мужского-среднего рода: *домишко, домишка,
>   домишку, домишко, домишком, о домишке*. Формы косвенных падежей
>   *домишки, домишке, домишку, домишкой* являются разговорными и восходят к начальной форме *домишка* (ср. у Некрасова: *Артикул ружьём
>   выкидывал, так что весь домишка вздрагивал*).

Дитмар Эльяшевич расставил все точки над «i».

Comment: Поглавнее? Но это же не его основная задача - грамматические формы определять. Этим должны заниматься универсальные и грамматические словари. Вот словарь Кузнецова считает, что он академический и некоторые сведения по грамматике предоставляет, но про "домишко" мало что сказал. Может быть, в  универсальном словаре Морковкина что-нибудь есть, хотя вряд ли. Не нравится мне форма "к домишку," и вообще,  темная какая-то история. Кстати, в вашем тексте есть вроде бы "от домишки к домишке". Получается, что это ненормативно? Неужели правильно "от домишка к домишку"?

Comment: Ни, Шарончик, заблуждение! Русское словесное ударение или Словарь трудностей - самое наивъедливейшее указательство.

Comment: Ну, ладно, пусть будет. Но у Вас-то задача практическая: как будете писать "о домишки к домишке"?

Comment: У меня: *Воистину удивительно, что горы сохраняют свой вековой уклад, потому-то от домишка к домишке - на сотни километров, - от перевала к перевалу всё так же и вьётся древняя, узкая, вымощенная камнем тропа.* А было *потому-то от домишки к домишке*.

Comment: Может ли надел земли принадлежать домишке? А здесь? Неужели правильно "домишку"? И вот такое предложение надо исправлять?  Правда, не успев подойти к своему домишке, Федул устал от радости, овладевшей им после «чекушки». [Юрий Петкевич. Живые цветы зимой (2001)]

Comment: Не надо "домишку", здесь дательный. Я, должно быть, неправильно падежи прочитала, исходя из окончаний, указанных в словаре. Щас подумаю и - исправлюсь. А  Петкевич пусть пишет как хочет, вон у него и чекушка закавычена... И вообще, ошибки не будет (домишко/домишка), только при докапывании до как надо ориентировка на "главный" словарь.

Answer (score 1):

```
       Не нравится мне форма "к домишку"
```

И мне не нравится, а всё потому, что в грамматику здесь вмешивается стилистика. Само слово относится к разговорной лексике (в научном и деловом стиле не употребляется).

По правилу это слово склоняется по образцу 2 склонения. Это сущ. мужского рода, но по виду похоже на сущ. среднего рода, как село, например, потому 
 и склоняется так же, как село: домишко, домишка, домишку, домишко, домишком, о домишке. Но в живой речи мы чаще слышим: *нет уже прежнего домишки, подойти к домишке, любоваться деревянным домишкой и т.д.*, с окончаниями, присущими склонению существительных женского рода. Здесь сказывается влияние разговорной речи, в которой слова типа домишко  изменяются по женскому склонению. Сейчас форма ***домишка*** устаревает, а когда-то была употребительна.(У Некрасова: *Артикул ружьем выкидывал, так что весь домишка вздрагивал*).

Сейчас в нормативном языке действует правило:

> § 70. Существительные с некоторыми суффиксами имеют особенности в
>   написании безударных окончаний. Существительные с суффиксом -ишк-
>   оканчиваются в им. п. ед. ч. на -а или -о: в словах **муж. рода одушевленных** и в словах жен. рода — **окончание -а**, в **словах муж. рода
>   неодушевленных и в словах сред, рода — окончание -о.** Ср., напр.:
>   *братишка, мальчишка, человечишка, котишка, службишка, мыслишка и*
>   ***домишко, городишко, заводишко, пальтишко, платьишко, молочишко***. Такие
>   же окончания имеют существительные с ласкательным (безударным)
>   суффиксом -ушк- (-юшк-): ср., напр., *дядюшка, тестюшка, соседушка,
>   соловушка, вдовушка, нянюшка, волюшка и хлебушко, чадушко, полюшко,
>   горюшко.*

http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=1804

Но в **Орфографическом словаре** Лопатина **начальной формы на -а нет, а вот остальная парадигма женского  склонения осталась как допустимая**, видимо, как раз как разговорный вариант:

> дом`ишко, -а и -и, **дат. -у и -е**, тв. -ом и -ой, мн. -шки, -шек, м.
>   Орфографический словарь. 2012

https://slovar.cc/rus/orfo/653866.html

Так что обе формы имеют право на существование: в нормативной книжно-письменной речи пользуемся формами второго склонения, в свободной устно-разговорной речи — формами первого склонения. 
http://lik-bez.com/publ/teksty/grammaticheskie_besedy/padezhi_imen_sushhestvitelnykh/70-1-0-491

Answer (score 0):

Тут на нормативность не надо смотреть. Если хотите выразить, что все дома маленькие, то "от домика к домику". Но если надо выразить, что дома не только маленькие, но и находятся в жалком состоянии, то "от домишка к домишке".

Comment: Что же у Вас склонение разное? Нужно: от домишка к домишку (2 скл.) или от домишки к домишке (1 скл). Кстати,  домишко не обязательно маленький и жалкий, это может быть ласковое название маленького домика.

Comment: Ой, простите, не стал продолжать... Мне кажется: "от домишка к домишкЕ" - говорит об однообразности; а "от домишка к домишкУ" - об усилении упадка, об ещё большей безобразности этой самой жалкости.

Comment: Ну не знаю, как  смешанные формы могут о чем-то говорить. Но, может быть, Ваше мнение кому-то покажется интересным.

Comment: Дык, по окончаниям это показывается. Чувствуется же.

Comment: Что ж, возможно кто-то чувствует одинаково с  Вами и поддержит Ваше мнение. Я чувствую только то, что нехорошо в одном сочетании  использовать разные склонения одного и того же слова. К тому же нормативность одной формы вызывает сомнение, о чем и был задан вопрос.

Comment: Падежи и склонения не зря в русском языке - возможность выразить разные черты.

Comment: Падежи - да, а склонения вряд ли. Склонение соответствует роду и основе существительного, а также частично касается категории одушевленности. Что Вы еще хотите от склонения, я не знаю, всё это чистая грамматика.